# Approve/reject edits on scripts

Tags: discussion, moderation

When I am reviewing posts for suggested edits, I frequently see edits which are attempting to edit scripts which other users have posted either as part of their question, or as an answer.

Should moderating/reviewing users be more inclined to reject or accept these edits, as small parts of changed scripts may not function as the user originally intended after another user has edited it?

If these edits are not ever going to be helpful, then should we add an info box somewhere on the website's info page warning against editing other user's scripts?

Comment: Most of these edits from what I have see are attempts at updating older scripts to 2.8+ versions of Blender I suspect. My view on this is that these edits should be made into a separate script, instead of entirely replacing the original one. Not only they may conflict with the authors original intent, there may be other adverse effects, like some users still using older versions prior to 2.8 expecting the answers to still work.

Comment: I think especially in questions it would be best to leave them as they are. Sometimes the problem for what the author tries to find a solution is caused by issues in his script, so editing that it works should rather be given as an answer, not an edit - for it would make the question obsolete. But if it's a scripting mistake others might also run into as well it would help them if they would find the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Leave it up to the author

Most of the suggested code edits are actually quite useful. However, programming is all about detail, so even if the suggested edit is an improvement to some extent or the edit makes the script even work in newer versions of Blender, the author may dislike the changes for some minor reason e.g. *coding style*.

I'd recommend to [image] the review if you have no idea whether it is actually a good or bad suggestion, because *the author will be notified* as well and can decide in the last resort.

See [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)

> If you aren't able to ascertain if the post is better or worse after the edit, click **Skip**.

> ... if you are not sure, **skip** the edit and leave it for someone who knows.